# How to do two way binding in vuejs with custom component in shopware?

Tags: vue-component, shopware

I am trying to add two way binding to custom admin component in shopware.

```
<range-slider v-model="vuejsvar"></range-slider>
```

**The problem is the v-model variable vuejsvar is not getting updated, as I change the value of the input range element specified below**.

The template twig file.

```
 <% range_slider %>
 <template>
    <div class="range-slider">
      <label v-if="hasLabelSlot">
      <slot name="label">
      </slot>
      </label>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1"  :value="currentValue" :name="name" v-bind="$attrs" @change="onChange" v-on="additionalListeners">
      <div class='range-slider__progress'>{{ currentValue }}</div>
    </div>
</template>
<% endblock %>
```

The issue in the below code.

```
 watch: {
        value(value) {
            this.currentValue = value;
        }
    },
```

This code updates the value for vuejsvar as [Object event] as i move the range slider. I event tried the following.

```
  watch: {
            value(event) {
                this.currentValue = event.target.value;
            }
        },
```

Still updates vuejsvar variable as [Object event].

**Full code**

The index.js file

```
const { Component, Mixin } = Shopware;
const { Criteria } = Shopware.Data;
import template from './range-slider.html.twig'; // template which will show data 
Shopware.Component.register('range-slider', {
    template: template,
    inheritAttrs: false,
    props: {
        value: {
            required: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required:true,
            default:''
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            currentValue: this.value,
        };
    },
    computed: {
        hasLabelSlot() {
            return (this.$slots['label']);
        },
        additionalListeners() {
            const additionalListeners = Object.assign({}, this.$listeners);
            delete additionalListeners.change;
            return additionalListeners;
        },
    },
    watch: {
        value(value) {
            this.currentValue = value;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(event) {
            this.$emit('change', event.target.value );
        },
    }
});
```

**I based my code of** https://github.com/shopware/administration/tree/trunk/Resources/app/administration/src/app/component/form/sw-text-field

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `v-model` then you have to fire the `input` event.

Check the Vue Docs: [Using v-model on Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

```
<input v-model="searchText">
```

Is the same as:

```
<input
  v-bind:value="searchText"
  v-on:input="searchText = $event.target.value">
```

So, you have to use the `input` event or catch the `change` event yourself.

Like this:

```
<range-slider :value="vuejsvar" @change="onChange"></range-slider>
```

and

```
methods: {
    onChange(event) {
            this.vuejsvar = event;
        }
    }
```

But than you don't need the `v-model` at all.

Check the playground:

```js
 var RangeSlider = {     
    template: '#range-slider', 
    props: {
        value: {
            required: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required:true,
            default:''
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            currentValue: this.value,
        };
    },
    watch: {
        value(value) {
            this.currentValue = value;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(event) {
            this.$emit('input', event.target.value );
        },
    }
};
  
var Main = {
    el: '#app',
    components: {
      'range-slider': RangeSlider,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        vuejsvar: 50
      }
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(event) {
            this.vuejsvar = event;
        },
    }
};

Vue.component('range-slider', RangeSlider)
const vm = new Vue(Main);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  vuejsvar: {{vuejsvar}}<br />
  range-slider: <range-slider v-model="vuejsvar" name="slider"></range-slider>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="range-slider">
<div class="range-slider">
      <label>
      <slot name="label">
      </slot>
      </label>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1"  :value="currentValue" :name="name" v-bind="$attrs" @change="onChange" >
      <div class='range-slider__progress'>{{ currentValue }}</div>
    </div></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It didn't work for shopware side of vue code. I added model { prop: 'currentValue', event: 'change' }, removed the watch object and data object and changed the prop value to currentValue and it seems working. Thanks.

Comment: `v-modal` is two-way. There is no need to mess around with event handling, as all that is done automatically when you use `v-modal`. You could even use it directly on config. e.g. `v-modal="config.myPropName.value"` and have it update the config object directly. E.g. When the user hits save, the config is automatically saved with minimal effort on our part, and no need to juggle data around internally.